# Infimum inequality comparing restrictions.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on the real line. Say we have two collections of sets $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ and $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^{m}$, where $n>m$ and
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_k &= \bigcap_{k=1}^{m} B_k = \emptyset \\
\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k &= \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}B_k 
\end{align}
Can I say that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \inf_{x\in A_k}f(x) \ge \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \inf_{x\in B_k}f(x).
$$
Intuitively the answer is yes, since the $B_k$ give less restrictions, thus the average infimum should be lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f$ the identity function. Let $m=2$ with $B_1 = [0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. Let $n = 3$ with $A_1= [0,1], A_2 = [0,1]$ and $A_3 = [1,2]$. Now your inequality reads $$\frac{1}{3} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
and we have a contradiction.

EDIT: This is a counterexample to the original question. For a counterexample to the modified one see the comments.

Comment: My apologies, the sets should be disjunct as they should present different restrictions.

Comment: Well what about $B_1=[0,1)$ and $B_2=[1,2]$ and $A_1 = [0,1/8)$, $A_2=[1/8,1/7)$ and $A_3 = [1/7,2]$?